# merge? or create a 3rd CW backup thread?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, merging

There's [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553/easy-incremental-backups-to-an-external-hard-drive) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/straightforward-system-and-file-backup-restore-for-linux) question on backups. I felt what the users were asking for was different enough (e.g. time machine clone vs external hard drives) to not initially merge them.

However, givent he overlap of answers I'm debating on merging them, and making it community wiki, or I could just leave them alone and ask a 3rd question and make that CW. I think that if *"how do I do backups"* is going tot be a frequently asked question, then we should have a CW for it. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think [Easy incremental backups to an external hard drive.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553) should be CW. It asks for backup software with fairly specific constraints. For the same reason I'm against merging it with the other question.

[Straightforward system and file backup/restore for Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1891) is a different matter: it doesn't have any requirement apart from the obvious must-run-on-my-system and perhaps an implied easy-to-use. I could see it be made CW after the fact.

But if you'd like to have a CW list of backup software, I think it's best to ask a new, CW, one-software-per-answer question. *Then*, close any new question that's satisfactorily answered by the CW question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I can see merging [1891](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/straightforward-system-and-file-backup-restore-for-linux) into [553](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553/easy-incremental-backups-to-an-external-hard-drive). I'm less convinced about forcing it CW; there's a different between questions that have many right answers and questions that are completely subjective and have no wrong answers; see the discussion [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55888)

Comment: Well I'm not thinking even so much about *many right answers* as I am the ability to improve individual answers, and the question. So far we've had 2 backup scenario's there are more... I suppose the real question is should we have only 1 backup Q&A? I'm thinking of doing it more to limit the amount that the same people have to answer.